# Printing from one instance of a string to another

Tags: java, string

Let's say I have this String:

```
[0 1 2]
[0 1 1]
[0 1 3]
[1 2 3]
[2 4 6]
[9 5 2]
[0 1 3]
```

I want to print everything from one instance of `[0 1 3` to the next instance of `[0 1 3]`. In this example, I want to print:

```
[0 1 3]
[1 2 3]
[2 4 6]
[9 5 2]
[0 1 3]
```

How would I do this in Java? In order words I'm asking is there a way I can use `substring` to somehow manipulate it to print this or do I have to get the index of the first instance, keep on removing until I reach the next one?

Comment: So this is a String with multiple lines?

Comment: Just print out the substring between the two, like you stated in your question...

Comment: Yeah it's a string with multiple lines. And how would I print out the substring between the two? indexof would only return the first occurrence right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by taking the substring starting from the first index of `[0 1 3]` to the second index of `[0 1 3]`. The second index is found by calling [`indexOf(str, fromIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-int-): this methods starts to look starting from the given index, so we give it the first found index (shifted so that it doesn't find the already found index).

The following code stores the String inside `str` and the looked-up sequence in `sequence`. The first index is retrieved. If it is found, we look-up the second index and, if that one is also found, we take the substring. We need to add `sequence.length()` when taking the substring to account for the final sequence that you want to keep.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "[0 1 2]\n[0 1 1]\n[0 1 3]\n[1 2 3]\n[2 4 6]\n[9 5 2]\n[0 1 3]";
    String sequence = "[0 1 3]";

    int firstIndex = str.indexOf(sequence);
    if (firstIndex >= 0) {
        int secondIndex = str.indexOf(sequence, firstIndex + sequence.length());
        if (secondIndex >= 0) {
            String result = str.substring(firstIndex, secondIndex + sequence.length());
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }

}
```

prints

```
[0 1 3]
[1 2 3]
[2 4 6]
[9 5 2]
[0 1 3]
```

Comment: Ah that's neat. Thank you very much!